# How to vectorize a function for integral2?

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I want to evaluate a double integral of the form 
$$\int_{-\infty}^a \int_{-\infty}^b \sum_{i,j}^K a_ia_jx^iy^j\exp(-x^2 - y^2 + xy)dx dy $$

where $a_i$ and $a_j$ are constants. Since the integral is linear, I can interchange summation and integration, but in this case I have to evaluate $K^2$ integrals and it takes too long. In that case I do the following:

```
for i = 1:K
   for j = 1:K
       fun = @(x,y) x.^i.*y.^j.*exp(-2.*(x.^2 + y.^2 - 2.*x.*y))
       part(i,j) = alpha(i)*alpha(j)*integral2(fun,-inf,a,-inf,b)
   end
end
```

It takes too long, so I want to evaluate only one integral, but I don't know how to vectorize $\sum_{i,j}^K a_ia_jx^iy^j\exp(-x^2 - y^2 + xy)$, namely, how to supply it to integral2. I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: I think some analytic simplification might help.  For starters, that's `exp( -2 * (x-y)^2 )`, so try a change of variables to `(x-y)^2`.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you just want to improve speed, you may try parfor.
2. Let $X=(x,x^2,\cdots,x^K)$, $Y=(y,y^2,\cdots,y^K)$, $A=(a_{ij})$ be a matrix with $a_{ij}=a_{i}a_{j}$, then
   $$\sum_{i,j}^K a_{i}a_{j}x^iy^j=XAY^{T}$$

I don't have integral2 function on my matlab, so I didn't test if it will improve the speed a lot.

Also, I think you need to use syms x and y, after you compute the $$XAY^{T}$$, then use matlabFunction to convert symbolic expression to function handle. Here it is my test code: syms x y; X=[x,x^2]; Y=[y,y^2]; Z=X*Y'; fun =matlabFunction(Z); ff=@(x,y) x^2+y^2; gg=fun(x,y).*ff(x,y);

Comment: Unfortunatelly it does not work. I tried    `fun = @(x,y)[x x.^2]*alpha*[y; y.^2].*exp(-2.*(x.^2 + y.^2 - 2.*x.*y))
integral2(fun,-inf,5,-inf,5)`     and I got     `Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in
@(x,y)[x,x.^2]*alpha*[y;y.^2].*exp(-2.*(x.^2+y.^2-2.*x.*y))


Error in integral2Calc>@(y)fun(xi*ones(size(y)),y) (line
19)
    @(y)fun(xi*ones(size(y)),y),y1i,y2i,opstruct.integralOptions),
    ...`
This function requires input of a particular type.

Comment: I think you need to use syms x and y, after you compute the $$XAY^{T}$$, then use matlabFunction to convert symbolic expression to function handle. Here it is my test code: syms x y;
X=[x,x^2];
Y=[y,y^2];
Z=X*Y';
fun =matlabFunction(Z);
ff=@(x,y) x^2+y^2;

gg=fun(x,y).*ff(x,y);

Comment: I tred to implement it, however, it is slower than `syms s1 s2
z = [s1 s2]*Oginv*[s1;s2];

f = (alpha(1)*(alpha(1) + 2*(alpha(2)*z + alpha(3)*z^2 + alpha(4)*z^3 + alpha(5)*z^4 + alpha(6)*z^5)) + ...
    alpha(2)*(alpha(2)*z^2 + 2*(alpha(3)*z^3 + alpha(4)*z^4 + alpha(5)*z^5 + alpha(6)*z^6)) + ...
    alpha(3)*(alpha(3)*z^4 + 2*(alpha(4)*z^5 + alpha(5)*z^6 + alpha(6)*z^7)) + ...
    alpha(4)*(alpha(4)*z^6 + 2*(alpha(5)*z^7 + alpha(6)*z^8))+alpha(5)*(alpha(5)*z^8 + 2*(alpha(6)*z^9)) +...
    alpha(6)*alpha(6)*z^10)*exp(-z/2); fun  = matlabFunction(f);
cdf2 = integral2(fun,-inf,a,-inf,b)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll need to have i and j be third and fourth dimensions, in order for there to be a chance that the code will work.

I also don't have integral2 (I use octave, integral2 is a new matlab function that octave doesn't yet have), so I can't test it, but I'd think something like this might work:

```
alphaset=zeros(1,1,K,K);
alphaset(1,1,1:K,1:K)=alpha(1:K)'*alpha(1:K);
i_set=zeros(1,1,K,1);
j_set=zeros(1,1,1,K);
i_set(:)=1:K;
j_set(:)=1:K;
fun=@(x,y)  x.^i_set.*y.^j_set.*exp(-2.*(x.^2 + y.^2 - 2.*x.*y));
part = squeeze(alphaset.*integral2(fun,-inf,a,-inf,b));
```

As I said, I can't promise that it'll work, because I don't know how integral2 works. But if you replace the integral2 with simply "sum(sum(fun([1,2,4],[3,-1,2])))", then it works as intended for that operation (that is, it sums over the x and y values, and the result is a matrix over the set of indices).